# Laravel. Не работает код jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Laravel 5.5. Сам jQuery подключён. Анимация на Bootstrap работает. Но код jQuery, в шаблоне, или из файла js, в папке `public/js/`, подключенный в header - не работает. Не может распознать `$`.

Comment: Проверь порядок подключения скриптов, в консоли проверь, есть ли глобыльная функция `$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не работает потому что весь код шаблона (не только html) но и js надо писать между тегами @section. У тебя скорее всего секция закрывается перед скриптом, и тогда подключение jquery обрабатывается после срабатывания самого скрипта. Убедится в этом ты можешь нажав F12 на странице - увидишь что весь твой скрипт вообще запускается первым в шапке, до подключений.

Comment: Точно! Из секции в шаблоне код заработал. Но почему он не работает из файла. Он расположен в том же  `public/js/`, в заголовке подключён после  jquery.